# Accessing base class functions in child class

Tags: perl

I have in my base class `use Storable qw/nfreeze thaw/;` but I cannot access `nfreeze` in my child class. I am calling it in child class like `nfreeze($data)`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Storable::nfreeze` and `Storable::thaw` are *functions* and not *methods* -- they do not expect an object of a particular type or a package name as their first arguments. In general, you call these subroutines directly (`nfreeze($data)`) rather than with indirect syntax (`$obj->thaw()`) and so you should not expect them to be in the set of inherited methods.

To use these functions in your child class, import them into your child package

```
package ChildClass;
use Storable qw/nfreeze thaw/;
```

or call the functions with their fully qualified subroutine names:

```
Storable::nfreeze($data);
BaseClass::thaw($data);
```

The second call works because `nfreeze`/`thaw` would have already been imported into the `BaseClass` namespace.